All groups of order $2010$ are solvable
Show that every group of order $2010 = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 \cdot 67$ is solvable. This is easy.
$n_{67} =1$ since $n_{67} \mid 30$ and $n_{67} \equiv 1 \mod 67$. Now, $P \in \mathrm{Syl}_{67}(G)$ is normal in $G$ and so $G/P$ is well-defined. But $P \cong \mathbb{Z}_{67}$ which is abelian, hence solvable. If I can show that $G/P$ is solvable, I will be done. Now, $|G/P| = 2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5 = 30$.

Lemma Any group  $G$ of order $|G|=pqr$ for $p,q,r$ primes with $p<q<r$ has a a unique Sylow subgroup.

Lemma Proof. Toward a contradiction, suppose not. Then $n_p \geq q, n_q \geq r$ and $n_r \geq pq$. Counting elements, $G$ has at least
$$|G| \geq q(p-1)+r(q-1)+pq(r-1)+1 = pqr+qr-q-r+1$$
$$=pqr+\underbrace{\left(qr-(q+r)\right)}_{>0} +1 > pqr = |G|$$
So at least one of $n_p,n_q,n_r=1$. $\square$
By the lemma, $G/P =2 \cdot 3 \cdot 5$. One of $G/P$'s Sylow groups are normal. Then if $Q$ is any Sylow group of $G/P$ (doesn't matter which), then $(G/P)/Q$ has order that is a product of two primes. By Burnside, $(G/P)/Q$ is solvable. Since $Q$ must be abelian ($|Q|=2,3,$ or $5$), $Q$ is solvable.
I have now shown that $Q$ is solvable and $(G/P)/Q$ is solvable which means $G/P$ is solvable. But now, in the bigger picture, $G/P$ and $P$ are solvable which means $G$ is solvable.
This is a pretty roundabout way of doing this and I have seen easier ways to do this, but I found it fun to continue breaking $G$ down into quotients until I could utilize Burnside. Any small mistakes aside, is this a valid way of approaching this kind of exercise?

Yeah this seems ok. I think Burnsides $p^aq^b$ is serious overkill though. It's pretty easy to prove directly a group of order $pq$ is solvable!

It depends on what you consider to be known, like Sylow theorems and similar results. I think, the lemma is well known and there is no proof necessary, because it is proved in every book on group theory. Even more, it is proved that every group of order $<60$ is solvable. So it is clear that $P$ and $G/P$ are solvable.

In fact , if you can use "big guns" , you can use that nonsolvable finite groups must have an order divisible by $4$. But it is good to use as easy methods as possible.
